# where is the preseed.cfg file for ubuntu 15 desktop

Tags: 15.04, 15.10, desktop-environments, preseed

**Anyone know where I can find a preseed.cfg file for installing an Ubuntu 15.04 (or 15.10) Desktop version distribution ?**

I need this for creating a Vagrant box with Packer.

Whereas I already a preseed.cfg which run correctly with Ubuntu15 but only for server version. When I try with Desktop version, the installation stop on available memory warning (but nothing real problem of memory).

Thank for your supply

*For example I already use this preseed.cfg :*

```
choose-mirror-bin mirror/http/proxy string
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i passwd/user-fullname string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-uid string 900
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server cryptsetup build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev linux-source dkms nfs-common
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
d-i time/zone string UTC
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server
```

freeze on this screen :

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/kaorimatz/packer-templates/blob/master/http/ubuntu-15.10/preseed.cfg Does that help at all? I know the situation that you're in-- I don't think it's on Ubuntu's web site at all.

Comment: Your file is very short for a preseed install and I don't think this is a Desktop ubuntu preseed. I already have a good preseed.cfg for Ubuntu server which run correctly but is not the question here.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to packer-ize desktop ubuntu?  Sorry, I'm not too sure.  It should work the same way as server ubuntu, but these preseeds can get real freaky.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific screen try

```
ubiquity ubiquity/download_updates boolean true
ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree boolean true
```

You might also want to add the locale, country, and keyboard choices

```
ubiquity time/zone select America/Los_Angeles

ubiquity countrychooser/shortlist string US
ubiquity languagechooser/language-name string English
ubiquity localechooser/supported-locales string en_US.UTF-8

ubiquity keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
ubiquity console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
```